# Planet, Telekinetic Alien Race, City with a "Shimmering" skyline

Tags: story-identification

I began reading Sci-Fi in the early 60s as a small boy, borrowing books from the library. Sometime between then and my early life after college, probably between 1965 and 1985, I read a book, novella or short story which included a very graphic scene where voyagers from Earth? encounter an alien race living in a city with a skyline that appeared from a distance to "shimmer". As they came closer they realized that the buildings were actually changing in real time. The beings therein had the power of telekinesis and they used it to change everything around themselves on a whim.
Anyone know the story to which I refer?

Comment: I vaguely remember this. Did the 'aliens' turn out be descended from Earth babies that had been saved from a wreck by actual aliens, and their psi powers trained? I thought it was by Alan E.Nourse, but can't find it.

Comment: Oh my...  This site and contributors are UNBELIEVABLE! Thank you both so much. I remember it all now. Rocket to Limbo is exactly right. Really helpful.

Comment: I got started on the quest to find this title after I accidentally stumbled on another one that's been haunting me for years. I knew I'd seen a great episode / TV movie about a cyborg with an artificial hand containing a talking computer and the engrams of the entire human race stored for future retrieval. Now that we can find and stream almost anything on TV, I wanted to watch it again, but couldn't recall its origin. The other day while reading Harlan Ellison's Wiki page, there it was, Bob Culp and The Demon w the Glass Hand. VOILA! Now I have both and no more nagging mysteries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a book by Alan E. Nourse I have somewhere; in Italian the title is "Il Pianeta Grigio" (The Gray Planet), the original 1957 title being [*Rocket to Limbo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_to_Limbo).

Wikipedia has the shimmering city scene quoted:

> The men trudge onward, over the pass, and down into the valley. The fog lifts and the men see a three-dimensional kaleidoscope, filled with people, floating several hundred feet above a meadow. Lars is taken into the city and meets up with Peter Bingham, Ganymede's other Officer-in-Training. Lars and Peter are treated as honored guests by the City-people, who possess the power of teledynamics, the ability to change the forms of matter and energy with a thought. Meanwhile, Planetfall and Ganymede are kept in storage and their crews kept in deep sleep.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's the one I was thinking of!

Comment: Oh my...  This site and contributors are UNBELIEVABLE! Thank you both so much. I remember it all now. Rocket to Limbo is exactly right. Really helpful.

Comment: I got started on the quest to find this title after I accidentally stumbled on another one that's been haunting me for years. I knew I'd seen a great episode / TV movie about a cyborg with an artificial hand containing a talking computer and the engrams of the entire human race stored for future retrieval. Now that we can find and stream almost anything on TV, I wanted to watch it again, but couldn't recall its origin. The other day while reading Harlan Ellison's Wiki page, there it was, Bob Culp and The Demon w the Glass Hand. VOILA! Now I have both and no more nagging mysteries.

Comment: @JD9727 welcome to the site! Since you've stated that this answer is correct, please mark it as such using the gray check-mark beside it.  That tells the system it's the right answer and rewards you and the answerer with a small reputation boost.